# Getting different sets according to dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I was solving a coding challenge problem and came across something I needed help with.

The problem is basically asking how many combinations of clothing a person can wear without being completely naked, with the clothing types given from input. Allow me to elaborate:

Input:

```
hat headgear
sunglasses eyewear
cap headgear
```

Output:

```
5
```

The reason the output is five in this example is because the possible combinations are `(hat)`, `(sunglasses)`, `(cap)`, `(hat, sunglasses)`, `(cap, sunglasses)` as you're only allowed to wear one item from each category.

My initial thought is to categorize each item according to their value, with the key being the specific item, and then using the `itertools.product` to find out how many possible combinations there are.

Is there a way to extract `[hat, cap]`, `[sunglasses]` from `{'hat': 'headgear', 'cap': 'headgear', 'sunglasses': 'eyewear'}`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another dictionary where the clothing type is the key and a list with all clothes of that type is the value:

```
clothes = {}
for wearable, clothing_type in your_dict:
    if clothing_type not in clothes:
        clothes[clothing_type] = ['']
    clothes[clothing_type].append(wearable)
# now clothes is {'headgear': ['', 'hat', 'cap'], 'eyewear': ['', 'sunglasses']}
```

if you only want the number 5, you can now multiply the length of each list and subtract 1:

```
possible_combinations = 1
for clothing_type, wearables in clothes:
    possible_combinations *= len(wearables)
possible_combinations -= 1
# 5
```

if you want the actual combinations, `itertools` is a really good idea:

```
combinations = [list(c) for c in itertools.product(*clothes.values())]
for combination in combinations:
    combination.remove('')
combinations = [c for c in combinations if c]

print(combinations)
```

Output:

```
[['sunglasses'], ['hat'], ['hat', 'sunglasses'], ['cap'], ['cap', 'sunglasses']]
```

Comment: You have to multiply `length + 1` (1 for nothing from this group).

Answer (score 2):

You are making your life to hard, i think.
if you dont need to know all the clothings, you can just set numbers for it: you can wear a hat, a cap or nothing on the head, so let the number for headgear=3, eyegear is 2 (sunglasses or nothing) and so on. for this you can start with just an dictionary of string, int with string is type of wearable and int is the number of elements plus 1.
At the end you can just multiply the numbers by walking through the dict and take 1 for completly naked away

Answer (score 1):

You can first store your items in a dictionary with keys representing a type of item and values as lists of the specific items for each type. For example:

```
gear = {
    'headgear': ['hat', 'cap', 'bandana'],
    'eyewear': ['sunglasses'],
    'footwear': ['socks', 'shoes']
}
```

Then you can go along the lines of your initial approach but find combinations of length 1 or more of each *type* of clothing (e.g. `(headgear,), (headgear, eyewear)` etc.). This would then give you the ability to calculate number of specific combinations achievable for each gear combination, which you can accumulate as a sum.

For example, for the gear combination `('headgear', 'eyewear')` in the above dictionary, the total number of specific combinations is `len(gear['headgear']) * len(gear['eyewear'])`, which is `3`. For the combination `('headgear', 'eyewear', 'footwear')`, it is `3 * 1 * 2 = 6`. Our final result is the sum of all these numbers for all possible lengths of combinations greater than 1. This gives us the following code:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

res = 0
for num_gears in range(1, len(gear) + 1):
    for gear_combination in combinations(gear.keys(), num_gears):
        res += reduce(lambda a, c: a * c, [len(gear[c]) for c in gear_combination])

print(res) # 23
```